# subst performance

Tags: windows-xp, subst

Does substing a directory affects the performance creating/reading/updating many small files in the substed volume? (will use svn there) If yes, how serious is the "penalty"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subst` uses native Win32 API [`DefineDosDevice()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363904(VS.85).aspx), which should not have any noticeable performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I use subst'd drives all the time, including with various version controls and builds and have never seen any degradation; I wouldn't worry about it.